# string split pattern java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to do a split of String array at the i th location. with a regex for 4 or more spaces.

i found a lot of information here and other sites, hence I came up with

```
String[] parts = titlesAuthor[i].split("    ");
```

so the split can happen between the title and authors name which contains either 4 or more spaces or does not exist as all.

Example:

```
titleAuthor[0] = Investigational drugs for autonomic dysfunction in Parkinson's disease          Perez-Lloret S
```

After running the above split, parts[0] is coming up as empty and part[1] has the complete string.

please help!

code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) { Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i); NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("TEXT"); line = (Element) title.item(0); titlesAuthor[i] = getCharacterDataFromElement(line); System.out.println(titlesAuthor[i]); parts = titlesAuthor[i].split(" "); System.out.println(parts[0]); System.out.println(parts[1]); }
```

Comment: So... we're supposed to fix your code without ever seeing the code?

Comment: its long with a lot of commented out stuff, should i post it all?

Comment: 1. You're splitting a String into a String[] (array), not a String array to whatever. 2. your example doesn't even compile, you need double quotes around the string literal. 3. You're splitting with exactly 4 spaces, so if you would have 10 spaces then you would split it up like this: ["before the spaces",/*we 'ate' 2*4 spaces*/"--"] (I changed spaces with dashes to see them)

Comment: Post [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
           Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);           
           NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("TEXT");
           line = (Element) title.item(0);
           titlesAuthor[i] = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
           System.out.println(titlesAuthor[i]);
           parts = titlesAuthor[i].split("    ");
           System.out.println(parts[0]);
           System.out.println(parts[1]);
}

Comment: @ShaheryarRajper, whenever you're asked to post code always add it to the question by editing it. Even better if you always include all the relevant code, so nobody will ask for it...

Comment: @ShaheryarRajper no. Just the part where you split the code. You should take the tour and take a closer look at the help-menu. They've got that stuff explained. As usual: "minimal, complete and verifiable example", so the snippet that you causes the issue and an example-input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To catch 4 or more spaces you need to indicate it with a +:

```
String[] parts = titlesAuthor[i].split("    +");
```

or:

```
String[] parts = titlesAuthor[i].split(" {4,}");
```

update: it looks like your xml doesn't look exactly as you think. In the code you provided add:

```
System.out.println(i + ":" + titlesAuthor[i] + ";");
```

and you'll see some spaces or new lines at the beginnng.

Comment: tried it, its leaving parts[0] empty and saving the title in parts[1]

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you fix the titleAuthor[0] in your question? I told you above that you need double quotes.

Comment: its one line from xml file among 1500 other records

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the input string is not what you think it is. Unless you give us an example input in the question, that can be compiled, I can't help further I'm afraid

Comment: yeah it was not, i used String regex = " {4,}";
           parts = titlesAuthor[i].split(regex); The first element has 6 empty spaces, the second has the title and third has the author

Comment: but what is titlesAuthor[i] ???? add a breakpoint, click on copy value, and add it to the question, but pay attention not to remove new-lines from it

Comment: its an array of string containing titiles and authors from xml tag

Comment: Give the EXACT, syntactically correct java String form the example that doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Use regex  `\s{4}`

Actually 4 is the number of spaces , you can change it to whatever number you want.

See the [demo](http://ideone.com/G7nNIU)

Comment: this matches exactly 4 spaces, as the one in the question

Answer (score 0):

THIS will skip the space..
split ("\s+")

Comment: this matches 1,2,3 spaces as well as space,tab,space, etc :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your code is splitting when it finds four consecutive spaces. The String that you are splitting above has ten consecutive spaces between:

```
"disease          Perez".
```

Thus, there is a split between the spaces. Pretend "#" is a space:

```
Investigational drugs for autonomic dysfunction in Parkinson's disease|SPLIT|null|SPLIT|##Perez-Lloret S
```

Your split will result in:

```
{[Investigational drugs for autonomic dysfunction in Parkinson's disease],[null], [##Perez-Lloret S]}
```

because your code found two instances of four spaces. The parts[1] is empty because there was nothing present in between the two splits.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but this doesn't explain why he doesn't get the 1st part of the sentence in parts[0]

Comment: in 1st part im getting 6 empty spaces, 2nd part the title and third the author if exists.
realized every line has 6 empty spaces in the beginning

Comment: Can you repost your code in a readable format.  When you post it, highlight it and press command 'k' if you are using a Mac.